# SQL query - Order by in the SQL query OR Sort a List<>

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, query-performance

I'm trying to improve some SQL queries.
I'm using the SQL server management studio 11 with SQL server 2012.
I'm working on a webform C# .Net (v4.5) project.

When I create my query directly from the SQL server management studio, I can use the "Execution Plan" to check what happens.

The bottleneck of my query is the "Order By". Is it better to sort the list directly from the code after the request or should I keep using the "Order By" of my SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Dependes, we need your schema and actual execution plan. But in general you can speed up your order by by creating a index covering it's columns

Comment: The Execution plan suggest me: "CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ...." to improve my query. "The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 42.5394%"

Comment: my view is same as @Oscar.It is very safe.

Comment: Be aware that the result might not be the same. ORDER BY will use the column's collation in the database while your code will follow the computer's current culture. (unless you specify another culture or collation of course)

Comment: Mind that the values assigned in a query-plan sometimes can be misleading. It's not because a part takes 50% that it also is responsible for half of the execution time. Have you tried doing a run with `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`; once with the ORDER BY and once without ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's better to use the SQL order by clause and most important reasons are that it won't cut your way in the future to implement paging of the data you are retrieving and you will be able to easily check with "Execution Plan" any performance issues connected with sorting results (like you did now). If you want to improve query performance, create index for columns included with the order by clause - if you are not sure how to do it in most cases you can use index suggested by the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

This is only my personal point of view.

I prefer to do it in code, because you can find a lot, powerful and quickly sorting algorithms.

Or you can use LINQ (if you are using C#), which is really powerful, and in a single line of code, you can do whatever you want, filter, sort, take x number, etc..  That´s why I prefer to do it in code.

Comment: +1 for the mention of LINQ, I agree that is the best way to go.

Comment: I already use LINQ. is sort a List<> from LINQ faster then the Order By of a SQL query ?

Comment: mmm, sincerly, I don´t know if it´s faster (I believe that yes). But at least with LINQ, you can do everything in a "short" way. I mean, without converting your TSQL query in a 20 lines query. LINQ id more efficient.

Comment: I will not down vote because linq is a perfect tool for some scenarios. But if OP is sorting millions of row returned from a complex query over a terabyte DB it ill be painfull slow compared to TSQL. @Taeeril is wrong, performance speaking you cannot beat a relational RDBMS with a library or framework.

Comment: I disagree, the OP does not state how many records they are returning. Just that it runs "slow". Given the limited knowledge of what the OP is after, you can't definitely state I am wrong. In all scenarios I have seen LINQ has preformed better.

Comment: The OP does not say the SORT is slow, only that it is a big part of the query plan. In my experience there is NO WAY you can make sorting locally faster than sorting on the RDBMS; assuming the latter is not starved for resources. The other way around; if you do the sorting on your web-server it might well be that you overload said machine and end up with an even slower user-experience.

Comment: Also, @OscarBralo, it's not because an instruction is 'just one line' that it is fast to execute. I like LINQ too, but I've met a lot of people who wrongfully think that it is fast because it looks compact.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SQL Server to sort your data. SQL Server allows optimizing performance by adding indexes, so you will be able to tune performance w/o modifying your code. LINQ (to objects) is just a programming language nicety, a set of extension methods on IEnumerable. From performance perspective it cannot stay close to highly optimized RDBMS. You can consider sorting data in in the code if

1. Your data set is small, in this case from performance perspective it doesn't matter.
2. You want to intentionally offload sorting from your busy SQL Server to another not-so-busy server, probably WEB Server.
3. List of sorting columns may vary from one request to another, so it is impractical or impossible to create indexes that satisfy every ORDER BY clause possible
4. You can sort a cached data set, so you don't want to bother your SQL Server by selecting the data again.
5. You use highly customized record comparison algorithm, that is hard to express using SQL script.

If you need to sort just on basis of a single set of columns, I would suggest reconsidering clustered index definition in your table. But this approach requires better analysis on what other queries are executed against the table.